# Unable to select a column in BigQuery

Tags: sql, firebase, google-bigquery

I am unable to select a column named: event_params.value.string_value

Here's my code:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT (event_params.value.string_value)
FROM
  `data-22.events_20200914`
```

My error:

> Cannot access field value on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRUCT<string_value STRING, int_value INT64, float_value FLOAT64, ...>>> at [2:26]

Comment: What error do you get?  What is the structure of the data?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: This is the error I got: Cannot access field value on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRUCT<string_value STRING, int_value INT64, float_value FLOAT64, ...>>> at [2:26]

Comment: I am sorry, I can't provide the dataset.

Comment: . . No one is asking for or wants actual data, just representative values to understand the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT event_param.value.string_value
FROM `mybits-54f8c.analytics_179636122.events_20200914 a CROSS JOIN
     UNNEST(event_params) event_param;
```

But this is just a guess.

Comment: Thank you so much @Gordon Linoff!! It is working perfectly fine.